# Admissible heuristic with wrap around

Tags: python

I want to create an admissible heuristic for a maze that can wrap around its walls. How is this possible? For example, if this was the maze (and the 1s are walls):

```
1 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 0 1 0 1 0
0 0 0 1 0 1 0
0 1 1 1 0 1 0
```

I could start at (0,2) and move down, down, down, left, left, left, and down, ending up at (6, 3).

I was thinking just the Manhattan distance would be useful, but the ability to move from one side of the maze to the other adds a layer of complexity that I don't think is entirely covered by the Manhattan distance alone.

Comment: As long as you choose the distance in the most efficient direction on each axis (i.e. min { distance when going left, distance when going right } and same for up/down), it is entirely covered by the Manhattan distance.

Comment: Ah, ok. So when implementing the min distance going left and right, are we talking about in reference to the goal?

Comment: Yes, that’s correct.